# how to save ms office documents directly to google documents

Tags: sync, google-docs, microsoft-word-2003

I tried this program called office sync but it does not work on ms office 2003.
It prompted me to input the username & password in google docs but when I try to look  up the document that I save 20 minutes later nothing show up in the recent documents.

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter your username & password, you have to "Save As.." and choose a name you want to call the file on google docs. This will upload the file to google docs, and from this point the document should be synced. I believe office sync is supported on Office 2003 and 2007.